# Cython: Overriding the `__cinit__` function with different parameters and signature

Tags: python, cython

I am interested in subclassing an existing Cython class (we'll call it `A`), which has say the following `__cinit__(self, int a, int b, *argv)` function signature.

My new class `B` would have the following `__cinit__(self, int a, int c, *argv)`, where `b` is no longer required, or used.

I want something along the lines of:

```
cdef class A:
    cdef int a
    cdef int b

    def __cinit__(self, int a, int b, *argv):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

cdef class B(A):
    cdef double c

    def __cinit__(self, int a, double c, *argv):
        self.a = a
        self.c = c
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If `b` is not used, then `B` shouldn't be a subclass of `A`. This is independent of Cython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not possible to do what you want.

The point of using `__cinit__` rather than `__init__` is that `__cinit__` is always called. The way that Cython ensures this is that it takes control away from you by arranging the calls to the base classes itself.

If possible it'd be better to use `__init__` instead of `__cinit__` unless you need to "guarantee to be called" since this gives more flexibility.

Your best option is probably to use a `staticmethod` factory function for class `B`. But you do lose the guaranteed call of `B.__cinit__`.